# ASP.NET Core application in K8S sometimes hangs on HostBuilder.Buid()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, kubernetes, .net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 application running in Kubernetes. During startup it simply runs typical code for a starting ASP.NET Core application. It now suddenly started to often, but *not always* hang somewhere in the `builder.Build()` call (which I figured out using Console.WriteLine calls not included in the code below) before entering the constructor of the `Startup` class, and after some time K8S will then kill the pod. If I disable the health probes, such hanging pods will continue to start up after several minutes and run normally.

I'm not sure how to investigate this further. What could cause this?

Is there something I can try to change in the code or in the configuration of the application? Or could there be something in Kubernetes that could cause this issue to suddenly appear?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = CreateHostBuilder(args);
    var host = builder.Build(); // hangs here
    host.Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
    builder = builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });

    return builder;
}
```

*Added:*
Running `kubectl logs <pod_name>` will only produce some logs from linkerd, which does not show me anything weird (the errors look like failing health check, which makes sense given the application does not fully start up):

````
Defaulted container "linkerd-proxy" out of: linkerd-proxy, <deployment_name>, linkerd-init (init)
[     0.020493s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy::rt: Using single-threaded proxy runtime
[     0.021883s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Admin interface on 0.0.0.0:4191
[     0.021913s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Inbound interface on 0.0.0.0:4143
[     0.021927s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Outbound interface on 127.0.0.1:4140
[     0.021935s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Tap DISABLED
[     0.021941s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Local identity is default.default.serviceaccount.identity.linkerd.cluster.local
[     0.021948s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Identity verified via linkerd-identity-headless.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8080 (linkerd-identity.linkerd.serviceaccount.identity.linkerd.cluster.local)
[     0.021954s]  INFO ThreadId(01) linkerd2_proxy: Destinations resolved via linkerd-dst-headless.linkerd.svc.cluster.local:8086 (linkerd-destination.linkerd.serviceaccount.identity.linkerd.cluster.local)
[     0.043719s]  INFO ThreadId(02) daemon:identity: linkerd_app: Certified identity id=default.default.serviceaccount.identity.linkerd.cluster.local
[    17.330501s]  INFO ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=80}:rescue{client.addr=87.233.137.147:47108}: linkerd_app_core::errors::respond: HTTP/1.1 request failed error=error trying to connect: Connection refused (os error 111) error.sources=[Connection refused (os error 111)]
[    37.318022s]  INFO ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=80}:rescue{client.addr=87.233.137.147:49918}: linkerd_app_core::errors::respond: HTTP/1.1 request failed error=error trying to connect: Connection refused (os error 111) error.sources=[Connection refused (os error 111)]
[    57.317661s]  INFO ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=80}:rescue{client.addr=87.233.137.147:55614}: linkerd_app_core::errors::respond: HTTP/1.1 request failed error=error trying to connect: Connection refused (os error 111) error.sources=[Connection refused (os error 111)]
[    77.317162s]  INFO ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=80}:rescue{client.addr=87.233.137.147:49574}: linkerd_app_core::errors::respond: HTTP/1.1 request failed error=error trying to connect: Connection refused (os error 111) error.sources=[Connection refused (os error 111)]
[    97.317333s]  INFO ThreadId(01) inbound:server{port=80}:rescue{client.addr=87.233.137.147:41688}: linkerd_app_core::errors::respond: HTTP/1.1 request failed error=error trying to connect: Connection refused (os error 111) error.sources=[Connection refused (os error 111)]```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what was causing this issue for me. The container was attached to a Persistent Volume Claim that contained at lot of left-over JSON data. All the app files were located in the root, which meant that when starting up ASP.NET Core saw these and went on scanning all of them for potential configuration, which usually took 2 to 5 minutes in my case. Placing the app files into a subfolder specified in the Dockerfile fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This code is generally written like below

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

}
```

Besides, you could check `kubectl logs <pod_name>` exception details.

Comment: Those are 100% equivalent and indeed it was precisely that before investigating this issue. I checked `kubectl logs <pod_name>`, but that gives only some things from linkerd, not the application itself (see addition to the question).

Comment: @JvS How about try catch (Exception ex) {  Console.WriteLine(ex); } to hanging codes?

Comment: No, indeed exactly the same can be seen in the console as before, as I would expect given unhandled exceptions are normally also printed to the console. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the .net core app rather than in kubernetes. If using Docker with Kubernetes you can see the logs from the Docker Desktop itself.

Docker Container:
[image]

Logs:
[image]

The `kubectl logs podname` command will also do the same work.

You can also create [Kubernetes Liveness Readiness Startup Probes](https://www.yogihosting.com/kubernetes-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/) to let kubernetes detects the health of apps and take proper actions for un-healthy apps.

Comment: I can inspect what is written to the consoles of the pods. We also have health probes and that's what's killing pods. I have recently found out that when I disable the health probes, after several minutes the hanging pods will continue to start up and run normally (I have added this to the question, too).

Comment: @JvS for containers are you using Docker? Might be a Docker issue. I would also say change to .NET 8.0 and see if any positives comes out.